# Getting incorrect link in BeautifulSoup python web scraper

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am writing a web scraper and am struggling to get the href link from a web page. The URL is https://www.seedinvest.com/auto I am trying to get the href links of their individual articles. Here is an example:

```
<a class="card-url full-size-content" href="https://www.seedinvest.com/soil.connect/seed"></a>
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re



URL = "https://www.seedinvest.com/offerings"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")


### Searching for all embeded company website links and displaying them

links = []
for link in soup.findAll(class_="card-url full-size-content"):
    links.append(link.get('href'))
print(links)
```

When I run my code, I get this:

```
[]
```

Can you help me find the right links?

Comment: You are using the wrong link thats why, use `URL = "https://www.seedinvest.com/auto"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're using the wrong URL in your code: `https://www.seedinvest.com/offerings` instead of `https://www.seedinvest.com/auto`?

Comment: Ahh yes!! Thank you for catching that. I was previously scraping the other URL and forgot to swap it out. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

It's working in [url](https://www.seedinvest.com/auto)

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


URL = "https://www.seedinvest.com/auto"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")


### Searching for all embeded company website links and displaying them

links = []
for link in soup.findAll(class_="card-url full-size-content"):
    links.append(link.get('href'))
print(links)
```

**Output:**

```
['https://www.seedinvest.com/nowrx/series.c', 'https://www.seedinvest.com/appmail/seed', 'https://www.seedinvest.com/soil.connect/seed', 'https://www.seedinvest.com/cytonics/series.c.2']
```

Comment: Ahh yes!! Thank you for catching that. I was previously scraping the other URL and forgot to swap it out. I appreciate the help!